# Update the sys.config file without restarting node

Tags: erlang

I would like to know if there is a sys.config file of an erlang node to be updated without restarting the node itself?

My usecase is to have variables in the env part of the sys.config configuration, where I constantly poll the sys.config to see if certain variables are true or false for various reasons like turning on or off features of a program on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sys.config` is only read at start time (and new release installation time). Are you aware of [`application:set_env/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#set_env-3)? If you are, in what way does it not meet your needs?